# Alert view is not displaying?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, nsnotifications

iam checking whether internet is available or not is bot am trying to show one alert and when i click this "Ok" button i want to exit app.But now this alert is not displaying and its not calling the delegate too.

in my connectiviy function

```
  if([[notification object] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]])
    {
        checkNetwork=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AssamKart" message:@"Device is not Connected To internet ,Please try again later " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [checkNetwork show];

    }
```

in my alert delegate

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

        if(alertView==checkNetwork)
        {

            if(buttonIndex==1)
            {

           //here i open some other viewcontroller
        }}


    }
```

please help..me...

Comment: Do not programmatically exit from an app!!

Comment: ok i will not quit ,,but still why the alert view is not displaying?

Comment: Did you check using breakpoint whteher focus goes to the portion where you have allocated AlertView ?

Comment: please see my answere. i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There must some minor issue with your code if you show all must be resolved but Major thing is as you asked

```
click this "Ok" button i want to exit app
```

No way to for this as [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27). "Don't Quit Programmatically". 
Never quit an iOS application programmatically 
because people tend to interpret this as a crash.

if there is some specific reason for this you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

As Human Interface GuideLines  by Apple you can not quit app programmatically.

probably your condition might not be getting true.

```
  if([[notification object] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]])
```

You could  try to debug your code and see it. Secondly if it is only about alert then just try to show the alert without condition and see if it displays.

Also how you defining `checkNetwork`?  you should make sure it is `retain` or type `strong`. If you are using iOS6 then use strong and make it as a property.

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIAlertView *checkNetwork;
```

Finally in your code you can access it using `self.` prefix.

```
 self.checkNetwork=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AssamKart" message:@"Device is not Connected To internet ,Please try again later " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. I would try putting a breakpoint at the IF statement

```
if([[notification object] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]])
```

to see if the code gets called. Also it might help to add the

```
<UIAlertViewDelegate> in the .h.
```

And again, don't quit programmatically!

Comment: If the condition is true then I don't think it's a problem with the UIAlertView. I added your code to one of my projects and it works fine (the UIAlertView is a ivar). Try running that code outside of a condition like @nsgulliver said.

Comment: and since you wanted to use the - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex to exit the app (which you hopefully won't do anymore), you can remove that method and the OK will automatically dismiss the UIAlertView.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you're displaying your alert view from the main thread, that is:

```
[checkNetwork performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hope it helps,
A.